# How to not fire an event recursively?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to send a form after a file has been uploaded successfully, and then clean that form to let the user upload another file, the problem is that If i upload the first time, the form get sent once, If I upload the second time, the form get sent two time while it should be sent one time only , Upload another file for 3rd time, the form get sent 3 times .

I want the form to be sent one time whenever the user upload a new file , no matter how many times he does that .

Here's my code :

```
 $("#send-pc").off('click').on("click",function(){
      var data = {};
        console.log('hi')
        myDropzone.processQueue()
        test_cpt = 0;
        myDropzone.on("queuecomplete",function(file){
          $("#form-pc").serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;})
          data["filename"] = myDropzone.files[0].name
          data["token"] = oauthToken
          console.log(data["filename"])
          test_cpt = test_cpt + 1
          $.post("/add-docs-pc",data).done(function(resp){
          if(resp == "200"){
            alert("Vos documents on été ajouté à la platforme")
            reset_form()
            myDropzone.removeFile(file)

          }
          else{
            console.log("ERROR")
          }
          })
        });//queuecomplete Callback

      });
```

When I check `test_cpt` when I upload another file for a second time it's 2, it should be one, so I'm sure that the event "queuecomplete" is being called recursively . How can I achieve what I want and getting out of this loop ? Is there way to kill that event without destroying my object ?

I'm looking for a general JS method not specifically related to DropeZone JS

Comment: Can you post more of the code surrounding the block you posted, such as the code above the `myDropzone.processQueue()` line?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I apologize, I've added more code .

Comment: No problem, it's not initally obvious where exactly a problem is, and trying to post a minimal concise example is perfectly fine and encouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like every time something is submitted, that outer click function runs - and every time that outer click function runs, a new handler is attached to `myDropzone` here:

`myDropzone.on("queuecomplete",function(file){`

You need to remove the handler once the response gets sent out, so that subsequent clicks, uploads, and `queuecomplete`s won't trigger the handler attached previously. Either declare the handler as a function and use `.off` at the end, or simply use jQuery's `.one` such that the handler gets unbound automatically once it's called:

```
function queueCompleteHandler(file) {
  $("#form-pc").serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;})
  data["filename"] = myDropzone.files[0].name
  data["token"] = oauthToken
  console.log(data["filename"])
  test_cpt = test_cpt + 1
  $.post("/add-docs-pc",data).done(function(resp){
    if(resp == "200"){
      alert("Vos documents on été ajouté à la platforme")
      reset_form()
      myDropzone.removeFile(file)

    }
    else{
      console.log("ERROR")
    }
  });
  // Remove the handler if you used `on` instead of `one`:
  // myDropzone.off("queuecomplete", queueCompleteHandler);
}

myDropzone.one("queuecomplete", queueCompleteHandler);
```

Comment: This seems very logica, I replaced my code with yours, but when I try to upload for a second time, the event "queuecomplete" is not executed, the file get sent to the server, but the queuecomplete event is not fired at all for the second time , why is it hapenning ?

Comment: My bad, I had to put the `myDropzone.on` in the click event of my button, it works like a charm now, I can't thank you enough ! I've spent 3 days on this bug .